Gzip filter performance issue
I am upgrading Spring 5.3.34 version to Spring 6.1.10. I upgraded the application successfully, but only problem is when I used a custom compression filter to gzip the response, it is taking more time. Here is my code.
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class CompressionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (acceptsGzipEncoding(httpRequest)) {
            httpResponse.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            GzipResponseWrapper gzipResponse = new GzipResponseWrapper(httpResponse);
            chain.doFilter(request, gzipResponse);
            gzipResponse.close();
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    private boolean acceptsGzipEncoding(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        String acceptEncoding = httpRequest.getHeader("Accept-Encoding");
        return acceptEncoding != null && acceptEncoding.contains("gzip");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // No initialization necessary
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup
    }

    private static class GzipResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        private GzipServletOutputStream gzipOutputStream;
        private ServletOutputStream outputStream;

        public GzipResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            super(response);
            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            gzipOutputStream = new GzipServletOutputStream(outputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
            return gzipOutputStream;
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            gzipOutputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private static class GzipServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

        private GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream;

        public GzipServletOutputStream(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
            gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(output);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
            // Not used
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            gzipOutputStream.write(b);
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            gzipOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
}

<filter>
        <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.filter.CustomCompressionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>compressionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  

Previoulsy when using Gzipfilter in Spring5 it is taking 209 milli seconds to get the response. Here is the code in Spring 5 web.xml
 <filter>
        <filter-name>gzipFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>gzipFilter</filter-name>        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

As Spring6 does not support Gzipfilter so used custom compression filter but getting the response in 1 minute.
Can any one please help how to reduce the  response time when gzip it,  in Spring 6.1.10
